# MongoDB and Spring Data. Get size of array in entity

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have such entity.

```
@Document
public class Entity{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Set<Integer> ids;
}
```

I need to get size of array ***ids***

How it can be done using Spring Data aggregation framework?

I'm trying something like this:

```
AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(where("id").is(id));
AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("ids");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, group);
template.aggregate(aggregation, Entity.class, Entity.class);
```

Seems like I'm doing it totally wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution!

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(match),
                Aggregation.project("ids"), Aggregation.unwind("ids"), Aggregation.group().count().as("count"));
```

Now it works fine, without obtaining all items from array.

**UPD:** This one is better

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.match(where("id").is(id)),
                Aggregation.project().and("ids").project("size").as("count"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this;

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(match(criteria),group("ids").count().as("count"));
```

This will produce :

```
{"yourPOJO":[{"ids":[...],"count":5},...]}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it produce me {"myPojo": [{"ids":[...], "count": 1, },...]}
And it's correct behavior, coz it counts how much such elements as "ids", and not how much elements they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(match(criteria),group("ids").count().as("count"),unwind("ids"),group("ids._id").count().as("count1"));
```

Comment: Thank you. It's not correct solution, but it helps me to find correct one.